# Архитектура приложения yii2 с админкой на angular 2

Tags: php, yii2, angular2

Как лучше устроить архитектуру приложения на базе yii2 и админкой на angular2? Пока что есть приложение yii2-basic с самим сайтом, модуль yii2 api (rest-api).

Answer (score 1):

Делаете роуты (с методами GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) для API, вешаете на них обработчики, используете мидлвари для того, чтобы принимать JSON и отдавать JSON, вот в общем-то и всё.